# Convert the Django traceback message to other language

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I use the Django as my backend, when I register the user, there return the error message, that is:"A user with that username already exists".

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

But how can I convert it to other language? if I use Korean or Spanish?

Comment: Look at Django's translation support - if a translation has already been set up for that error then it's just a matter of enabling the setting and configuring which language a given user uses https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

Comment: @JohnCarter I'd upvote that as the answer to this question so you may want to switch that from being a comment.

Comment: @JohnCarter Thank you.

Comment: Note however there is something wrong if the error is being output in that format; the user shouldn't see it as a dict. You should show the template.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I use the Django-Rest-Framework as the API provider, how to show the template?

Comment: You should show some code.